# Auto download attachments via imap on ubuntu

Tags: exchange-server, ubuntu-16.04

how, on ubuntu 16.04 tls, can i connect to an inbox via imap and download all the attachments from incoming mails. and submit those attachments to cuckoo. the method should be via the terminal, and i need to insert it to the rc.local so it would load when i restart the machine

Comment: Not sure what Cuckoo is.. Did you mean a [cuckoosandbox](https://cuckoosandbox.org/)? Then you do not specify your Exchange version and if you wish to perform that via IMAP, POP3 or EWS as it could be that some of them aren´t enabled on the target environment. So please review your question and add more details.

Comment: you are correct, im reffering to cuckoo sandbox.
i will re-phrase my question:
how, on ubuntu 16.04 tls, can i connect to an inbox via imap and download all the attachments from incoming mails.
and submit those attachments to cuckoo.
the method should be via the terminal, and i need to insert it to the rc.local so it would load when i restart the machine.